# Auth0 and Angular 2: login and routing failing using the login widget

Tags: angular, jwt, angular2-routing, auth0

I am starting to develop web applications and chose Angular 2 as the front-end framework. I'm currently trying out Auth0 for user authorisation.
The problem is as follows:
I am trying to implement a landing page login -> redirect functionality. Immediately after opening the website it should check if there is a user's token in the `localStorage` and then either show the login widget or redirect to the home page. But I have ran into this very nasty bug:

When i'm logging in, the page refreshes and the widget appears again: `tokenNotExpired()` for some reason returns `false`. I press to login again with the same credentials - page refreshes, login widget disappears, logging shows that `tokenNotExpired()` is returning `true` now, but my redirect still doesn't work. If I now just enter my base address, `http://localhost:4200`, it successfully redirects me to `home` and `tokenNotExpired()` returns `true`.

I tried debugging it but without any luck - I can't find where it is failing.

Essentially, I am very sure there are problems in the way I approach coding the redirect feature, since my lack of experience. I would very kindly appreciate any help, been sitting on this for a while.

I'm including excerpts of my code omitting the redundant parts. I am injecting the Auth service globally by bootstrapping it in main.ts.

**app.routes.ts:**

```
import {provideRouter, RouterConfig} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthGuard} from './secure/auth.guard';
import {AdminGuard} from "./secure/admin.guard";

import {UserHomeComponent} from "./main/user-cpl/user-home.component";
import {AdminHomeComponent} from "./main/admin-cpl/admin-home.component";
import {LoginPageComponent} from "./login/login-page.component";

const APP_ROUTES: RouterConfig = [

  { path: 'home', canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: UserHomeComponent },
      { path: 'admin', component: AdminHomeComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
      ] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER = [
  provideRouter(APP_ROUTES)
];
```

**login-page.component.ts:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Auth} from '../secure/auth.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'login-page-component',
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>  
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: Auth, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit():any {
    console.log('LOGGED IN - ' + this.auth.loggedIn());
    if (this.auth.loggedIn()) {
      if (this.auth.isAdmin()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home/admin']);
      } else if (!this.auth.isAdmin()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }

    } else {
      this.auth.login();
    }
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';

declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock('omitted', 'omitted', {
    closable: false
  });

  //Store profile object in auth class
  userProfile: any;

  constructor() {
    // Set userProfile attribute if already saved profile
    this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

      // Fetch profile information
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) => {
        if (error) {
          // Handle error
          alert(error);
          return;
        }

        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        this.userProfile = profile;
      });
    });
  }

  login() {
    this.lock.show({
      callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/home'
    });
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('profile');
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    this.userProfile = undefined;
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  isAdmin() {
    return this.userProfile && this.userProfile.app_metadata
      && this.userProfile.app_metadata.roles
      && this.userProfile.app_metadata.roles.indexOf('admin') > -1;
  }
}
```

**auth.guard.ts:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {CanActivate} from '@angular/router';
import {Auth} from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: Auth, private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.auth.loggedIn()) {
      console.log('AUTH GUARD PASSED');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('BLOCKED BY AUTH GUARD');
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**admin.guard.ts:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {CanActivate} from '@angular/router';
import {Auth} from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: Auth, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.auth.isAdmin()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In `auth.login()` your attribute should be `callbackURL`.  I believe that this is case sensitive for OAuth.

Comment: @ghg565 yes, I changed it but it does not have any effect on it. I also realised it does not use the callbackURL to redirect anywhere, instead it goes back to the login page and doesn't store the credentials the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set `redirect: false` in the configuration since it is a single page app. Auth0 will otherwise make a GET call to the `redirectUrl`. This call is preventing your `authenticated` event from firing up. Thus, in your **auth.service.ts** file:

```
lock = new Auth0Lock('omitted', 'omitted', {
  closable: false,
  auth: { // <--- mind this nesting
    redirect: false
  }
});
```

This will invoke the 'authenticated' event in the service on login. You probably also want to redirect the user once login is done. Thus, in the callback invoke `this._router.navigate(['path'])`. Don't forget to `import { Router } from 'angular/router'` and creating an instance in the constructor: `constructor(private _router: Router) {}`.

Comment: Setting redirect to false will enable 'Popup mode', which has the following warning in the docs: There is a known bug that prevents popup mode from functioning properly in Android or Firefox on iOS, and in Internet Explorer under certain circumstances. As such we recommend either only using redirect mode or detecting these special cases and selectively enabling redirect mode.